# Mac: easiest way to move multiple duplicate file names to same directory

Tags: osx, directory, mv

I have two folders with hundreds of video files that have duplicate names (such as vid1,vid2,etc). I just want to put all these files in the same folder and I don't care about them being renamed. When I drag a couple of files over it gives me the option to "Keep both", but when I try and drag this large amount of files it no longer gives me that option. I tried using `mv` command in terminal, but it seems to either replace or skip rather than 'keep both'.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the interactive options `-i` to keep duplicate files. If you redirect /dev/null into mv, all overwrite questions are answered with no:

```
cd /folder1
mv -i * /folder2 < /dev/null
```

After this command, all files left in folder1 are name duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for the names, why not simply copy all files with a prefix:

```
for file in dir2/*.mov; do mv "$file" dir1/2-"${file#*/}; done
```

(assuming you are using bash)